# Android room relations

Tags: android, spring-data-jpa, android-room

I have two entities that looks like this (simplified for reading purposes).

```
@Entity
public class Machine {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id
}

@Entity
public class MachineType {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id
}
```

What i want is the Machine entity to have a machine type.
I tried foreign keys, but my issue with that is that it don't act at all like the Spring Boot equivalent Persistence library where the foreign entity is included (i don't know how to explain this well enough). Heres an example from the REST-api in spring:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo",
    "machineType": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "bar"
    }
}
```

While room with foreign keys makes is like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo",
    "machineType_id": 1
}
```

This creates all sorts of trouble for me when putting objects back to the API.
So i tried with @Relation annotation since that sounded like what i needed, but that only created an error since the columns from the related object is included in the main entity, so i get two "id" columns.

> error: Multiple fields have the same columnName: id. Field names: id, machineType > id.

Please help. Am i on the wrong track? Is there a better solution for my problem?

Comment: all complete Entity class code ,not simpleted

Comment: Have you used @Relation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you insert data change table column name like below code and you can give column name in room database.

```
@Entity
public class Machine {
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "nId")
    private long id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "machineType_id")
    private long mId;

}

@Entity
public class MachineType {
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "machineType_id")
    private long id;
}
```

when you getting api response for same class that time unique key for server that time give particular field in server key using this key word like below ..

```
@SerializedName("name")
@ColumnInfo(name="sName")
private String name;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Embedded Annotation can be useful in this case.
[Link for embedded](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data.html#nested-objects)

So what you need to do is have a MachineType Object in the Machine class and annotate it with `@Embedded`. Also in order to avoid having two variables with the same name , in this case it is `id` , you can use this annotation
`@ColumnInfo(name = "some_column_name")` to have a column name which is differs from the variable name.

[Link for Column Info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Entity.html)